# Android application(Kotlin) crashing with no issue in the code

Tags: android

The application crashes as soon as it is run to the emulator. The main code runs perfectly but when it comes to the implementation in the emulator, it runs and the app crashes. The error is shown below:

```
2020-07-20 14:05:48.662 9135-9135/com.sam.sabinomeals E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.sam.sabinomeals, PID: 9135
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.sam.sabinomeals/net.sam.sabinomeals.SplashActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "net.sam.sabinomeals.SplashActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.sam.sabinomeals-QJkZ4ORKUV6qLdDBZZ2Jvw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.sam.sabinomeals-QJkZ4ORKUV6qLdDBZZ2Jvw==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
            at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
         Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "net.sam.sabinomeals.SplashActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.sam.sabinomeals-QJkZ4ORKUV6qLdDBZZ2Jvw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.sam.sabinomeals-QJkZ4ORKUV6qLdDBZZ2Jvw==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
            at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1243)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3182)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
            at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

The code below is for the splashactivity, it seems to be sure but I think you can still go through it.

```
package com.sam.sabinomeals

import android.Manifest
import android.app.DatePickerDialog
import android.content.Context
import android.content.DialogInterface
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.ConnectivityManager
import android.net.NetworkCapabilities
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.text.TextUtils
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
import com.google.firebase.database.*
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId
import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter
import com.karumi.dexter.MultiplePermissionsReport
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.multi.MultiplePermissionsListener
import com.sam.sabinomeals.Remote.ICloudFunctions
import com.sam.sabinomeals.Remote.RetrofitCloudClient
import com.sam.sabinomeals.commons.Common
import com.sam.sabinomeals.models.BraintreeToken
import com.sam.sabinomeals.models.UserModel
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers
import io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_splash.*
import net.sam.sabinomeals.R
import org.jetbrains.anko.longToast
import org.jetbrains.anko.toast
import java.util.*

class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var userReference: DatabaseReference
    val SPLASH_SCREEN: Long = 5000
    lateinit var handler: Handler

    private  var compositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable?= CompositeDisposable()
    lateinit var cloudFunctions: ICloudFunctions

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)
        cloudFunctions= RetrofitCloudClient.getInstance().create(
            ICloudFunctions::class.java)
        window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
        userReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.USER_REFERENCE)

        //Animation
        val logo_animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            R.anim.top_animation)
        val txt_animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            R.anim.bottom_animation)

        logo_splash.animation = logo_animation
        urbanfood.animation = txt_animation

        handler = Handler()
        checkInternet()
    }

    private fun checkInternet() {
        Dexter.withActivity(this)
            .withPermissions(Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            .withListener(object :MultiplePermissionsListener{
                @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                override fun onPermissionsChecked(p0: MultiplePermissionsReport?) {
                    if (isOnline(this@SplashActivity)) {
                        // showHome()
                        val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
                        if (currentUser != null) {
                            checkUserFromFirebase(currentUser)
                        } else {
                            longToast("Kindly Login")
                            showLogin()
                        }

                    } else {
                        longToast("Please ensure you are connected to the Internet")
                        handler.postDelayed({
                            finish()
                        }, SPLASH_SCREEN)
                    }
                }

                override fun onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(
                    p0: MutableList<PermissionRequest>?,
                    p1: PermissionToken?
                ) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder(this@SplashActivity)
                        .setTitle(R.string.internet_permission_title)
                        .setMessage(R.string.internet_permission_message)
                        .setNegativeButton(
                            android.R.string.cancel,
                            DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->
                                dialog.dismiss()
                                p1?.cancelPermissionRequest()
                            })
                        .setPositiveButton(
                            android.R.string.ok,
                            DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->
                                dialog.dismiss()
                                p1?.continuePermissionRequest()
                            }).show()
                }

            } ).check()

    }

    private fun checkUserFromFirebase(currentUser: FirebaseUser) {
        userReference.child(currentUser.uid)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                    showRegisterDialog(currentUser)
                    finish()
                }

                @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                    if (p0.exists()) {
                        val userModel = p0.getValue(UserModel::class.java)
                        if (userModel != null) {
                            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!
                                .getIdToken(true)
                                .addOnFailureListener{
                                        exception ->  Toast.makeText(this@SplashActivity,""+exception.message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                }
                                .addOnCompleteListener{
                                    Common.authorizeToken=it.result!!.token
                                    val headers = HashMap<String,String>()
                                    headers["Authorization"] = Common.buildToken(
                                        Common.authorizeToken)
                                    compositeDisposable!!.add(cloudFunctions.getToken(headers)
                                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                        .subscribe({braintreeToken: BraintreeToken? ->
                                            goToHomeActivity(userModel,braintreeToken!!.token)
                                        },{throwable: Throwable? ->
                                            Toast.makeText(this@SplashActivity,""+throwable!!.message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                        }))
                                }


                        }
                    } else {
                        showRegisterDialog(currentUser)
                    }
                }

            })

    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private fun isOnline(context: Context): Boolean {
        val connectivityManager =
            context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val capabilities =
            connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.activeNetwork)
        if (capabilities != null) {
            if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                Log.i("Internet", "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR")
                return true
            } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                Log.i("Internet", "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI")
                return true
            } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET)) {
                Log.i("Internet", "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET")
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    private fun showLogin() {
        handler.postDelayed({
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()


        }, SPLASH_SCREEN)
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private fun showRegisterDialog(currentUser: FirebaseUser?) {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        builder.setTitle("Updated Profile")
        builder.setMessage("Please fill in your information")

        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(this)
            .inflate(R.layout.layout_register, null)

        val edt_name = itemView.findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.edt_name)
        val birth_date = itemView.findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.birth_date)
        val edt_address = itemView.findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.edt_address)
        val edt_phone = itemView.findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.edt_phone)
        //setPhone
        edt_phone.setText(currentUser!!.phoneNumber)

        //Date
        birth_date.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            val c = Calendar.getInstance()
            val mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
            val mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
            val mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

            val datePickerDialog =
                DatePickerDialog(
                    this,
                    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
                        birth_date.setText("" + dayOfMonth + "/" + month + "/" + year)
                    },
                    mYear,
                    mMonth,
                    mDay
                )

            datePickerDialog.show()
        })

        builder.setView(itemView)
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, which -> dialog.dismiss() }
        builder.setPositiveButton("Record") { dialog, which ->
            if (TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(edt_name.text.toString())) {
                toast("Enter your name")
                return@setPositiveButton
            } else if (TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(edt_address.text.toString())) {
                toast("Enter your address")
                return@setPositiveButton
            }

            val userModel = UserModel()
            userModel.uid = currentUser.uid
            userModel.name = edt_name.text.toString()
            userModel.address = edt_address.text.toString()
            userModel.aniversaire = birth_date.text.toString()

            userReference.child(currentUser.uid)
                .setValue(userModel)
                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!
                            .getIdToken(true)
                            .addOnFailureListener{
                                exception ->  Toast.makeText(this,""+exception.message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            }
                            .addOnCompleteListener{
                                Common.authorizeToken=it.result!!.token
                                val headers = HashMap<String,String>()
                                headers.put("Authorization",
                                    Common.buildToken(
                                        Common.authorizeToken))
                                compositeDisposable!!.add(cloudFunctions.getToken(headers)
                                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                    .subscribe({braintreeToken: BraintreeToken? ->
                                        dialog.dismiss()
                                        goToHomeActivity(userModel, braintreeToken!!.token)
                                    },
                                        {throwable: Throwable? ->
                                            dialog.dismiss()
                                            Toast.makeText(this,""+throwable!!.message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                        }))
                            }
                    }
                }
        }

        //Important
        val dialog = builder.create()
        dialog.show()

    }

    private fun goToHomeActivity(
        userModel: UserModel?,
        token: String
    ) {
        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance()
            .instanceId
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Toast.makeText(this,""+exception.message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                Common.currentUser= userModel
                Common.currentToken=token
                startActivity(Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java))
                finish()
            }
            .addOnCompleteListener { task->
                if(task.isSuccessful){

                    Common.currentUser= userModel
                    Common.currentToken=token
                    Common.updateToken(this,task.result!!.token)
                    startActivity(Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java))
                    finish()
                }
            }


    }

}
```

Comment: what's the package of `SplashActivity`?

Comment: Show the code of splash activity and have you registered splashActivity in manifest?

Comment: @Blackbelt splashactivity is the opening page of the application

Comment: post up code too

Comment: @CodeDexter SplashActivity code is in hundreds, should I still send it? Also, what do you mean by register activity in the manifest

Comment: Says `net.sam.sabinomeals.SplashActivity` doesn't exist. Maybe the error is in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I think you got your answer by from @EpicPandaForce what registering an activity in manifest means ;)

Comment: @CodeDexter Thanks a milion!

Answer (score 1):

It's because your AndroidManifest.xml is looking for `net.sam.sabinomeals.SplashActivity`, but your activity is actually in `com.sam.sabinomeals.SplashActivity`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, the app is up!

Comment: I have a smaller crash, can I run it by you as well? Please

Comment: That's a new question tbh

Comment: Hehe yes I would but I'll refer to you account!